# How to read voltage using expander pi?

Tags: readwrite

I am trying to read voltage using ADC of expander pi. when I connect one sensor the output is correct but when I connect more than 1 sensor the reading is not right. help me out on  this issue. I am using the following link to read adc voltage
https://github.com/abelectronicsuk/ABElectronics_Python_Libraries/tree/master/ExpanderPi

**Update:**

I want to measure voltage from 3 different sensors.  I have connected the output via jumper wire with the adc channel pins, and have connected the ground pin of the circuit with expander pi.  If I connect only 1 sensors output with the adc i get the voltage near to that of measured via digital multimeter,  with a drop of 0.11 volts but when I connect one more the reading goes to 0.0 the reference voltage is sef to default i.e 4.096

```
adc = ADC() # create an instance of the ADC


# set the reference voltage. this should be set to the exact voltage

# measured on the Expander Pi Vref pin.

adc.set_adc_refvoltage(4.096)


while True:

    # read the voltage from channel 1 and display on the screen

    print adc.read_adc_voltage(1)

    time.sleep(0.5)
```

To measure voltage from different pins m simply changing

```
adc.read_adc_voltage(2)
```

Comment: We need to see the specific code you are using, and  some pics of the connections. How do you know the reading is wrong?